# Optimize the display of pictures

Tags: java, android

There was a problem. I want to cache an image to display in the list. For a smooth scroll. I use the ready-made universal-image-loader library. The problem is that in order to display the image the library needs an URL.

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader
**libary**

```
@Override
public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap 
       loadedImage) {}
@Override
public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
    ...
}
@Override
public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
    ...
}
@Override
public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
    ...
}
```

*How can I use this library if the image comes to me through the network, and I don’t have links to it?*
**I have only a bit map**

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
            imageLoader.loadImage(url, new SimpleImageLoadingListener(){

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view,
                    Bitmap loadedImage) {
            super.onLoadingComplete(imageUri, view, loadedImage);

            //Write your code here
            }

        });
```

Comment: Sory i not have *String imageUri*